# Git flow release - actualizar origin

Tags: git, git-flow

Siguiendo el workflow de git flow entiendo que tras hacer un

```
git flow release finish '0.1'
```

con este comando automaticamente se hace un **merge** de la release a las ramas **develop** y **master**.

Para seguir un correcto flujo de trabajo en un equipo debería hacer un push a origen de las ramas develop, master y el tag?

Comment: Git flow no te recomienda cuando pushear las ramas, simplemente es una recomendación de nomenclatura de las ramas, y la dirección y el momento de los mergeos. El momento de hacer push de tus cambios es decisión tuya. Yo en tu situación, si se que no voy a dejar en mal estado alguna de las ramas, pushearía todo (incluido el tag y la rama release si no lo has hecho).

Comment: Gracias @ordago !